# Perl 6 - Is it possible to create an attribute trait that set a meta-attribute?

Tags: object, attributes, immutability, traits, raku

I try to create an attribute trait. The use case is to mark some attributes of a class as "crudable" in the context of an *objects-to-documents-mapping* while other are not.

```
role crud {
    has Bool $.crud is default(True);
}

multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute $a, crud, $arg) {
    $a.container.VAR does crud($arg);
}

class Foo {
    has $.bar is rw;

    # Provide an extra nested information
    has $.baz is rw is crud(True);
}
```

By reading and adapting [some example code](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S14-traits/attributes.t), I managed to get something that seems to do what I want. Here is [a snippet with test case](https://glot.io/snippets/euidhofsx3).

When I instantiate a new `Foo` object and set the `$.bar` attribute (that `is` not `crud`), it looks like that:

```
.Foo @0
├ $.bar is rw = 123456789
└ $.baz is rw = .Scalar+{crud} @1
  └ $.crud +{crud} = True
```

What I understand from this is that the `$.baz` attribute got what I call a *meta-attribute* that is independent from its potential value.

It looks good to me (if I understood correctly what I did here and that my traits use is not a dirty hack). It is possible to reach `$foo.baz.crud` that is `True`. Though, I don't understand very well what `.Scalar+{crud}` means, and if I can set something there and how.

When I try to set the `$.baz` instance attribute, this error is returned:

```
Cannot modify an immutable Scalar+{crud} (Scalar+{crud}.new(crud => Bool::True))
  in block <unit> at t/08-attribute-trait.t line 30
```

Note: This is the closest thing to a working solution I managed to get. I don't need different crud settings for different instances of instantiated Foo classes.

I never want to change the value of the boolean, in fact, once the object instantiated, **just providing it to attributes with `is crud`**. I am not even interested to pass a `True` or `False` value as an argument: if it would be possible to just set the boolean trait attribute  to `True` by default, it would be enough. I didn't manage to do this though, like:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute $a, :$crud!) {
    # Something like this
    $a.container.VAR does set-crud;
}

class Foo {
    has $.bar is rw;
    has $.baz is rw is crud;
}
```

Am I trying to do something impossible? How could I adapt this code to achieve this use case?

Comment: Could you explain what `does crud($arg)` does given that `crud` doesn't take arguments? Or, given that it seems like bogus code and given that you're saying it's not relevant to your focus in this question anyway, edit it out? In other words, make the last bit of code the core of the question and throw the first bit of code away. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh! Given the simplified version of the question (ignoring `$arg`), it suddenly seems to me that you are just trying to do what `role crud {}; class Foo { has $.baz is rw is crud }; say Foo.new.baz ~~ crud; # True` should do instead of what it currently does, namely complaining that "is trait on $-sigil variable not yet implemented. Sorry.". Am I miles off or... ?

Comment: And if I'm not miles off, what about the work-around of `role crud {}; class Foo { has @.baz is rw is crud }; say Foo.new.baz ~~ crud; # True`, i.e. using an array instead of a scalar?

Comment: Thanks @raiph , it was much more simple than what I was trying to do!

Comment: I'm confused by both what I wrote and what you wrote. :) Having poked at things I now don't understand what happens with `has $.baz is rw is crud` or `has @.baz is rw is crud`. And I don't understand whether you are saying I was (unhelpfully?) *over* simplifying or (helpfully?) simplifying. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my bad. I meant you *helpfully* helped by simplifying the code and made me think better of what I was doing. I consider that a "less complex code" was better, right? Then, about the `@.baz` array attribute, I admit that I didn't understood this part, but it showed me the path for a method provided by the overall tools I am developing, that return all  "CRUD" attributes included in a class. It was the main aim after all  :-)  . Confusion bringing solutions, maybe?

Comment: Thanks. "Confusion bringing solutions" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things going on here.  First of all, the signature of the `trait_mod` looks to be wrong.  Secondly, there appears to be a bad interaction when the name of a trait is the same as an existing role.  I believe this should be an NYI exception, but apparently it either goes wrong in parsing, or it goes wrong in trying to produce the error message.

Anyways, I think this is what you want:

```perl6
role CRUD {};  # since CRUD is used as an acronym, I chose to use uppercase here

multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute:D $a, :$crud!) { # note required named attribute!
    $a.^mixin: CRUD if $crud;  # mixin the CRUD role if a True value was given
}

class A {
    has $.a is crud(False);  # too bad "is !crud" is invalid syntax
    has $.b is crud;
}

say "$_.name(): { $_ ~~ CRUD }" for A.^attributes; # $!a: False, $!b: True
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Elizabeth, it helps a lot! It was difficult to find how to do  this by myself as I started to work with Perl6 last week only after reading the "Perl 6 Introduction" by Naoum Hankache (very clear and effective for a quick start). I am waiting for a copy of the "Perl6 at a glance" book and feel very excited about discovering more.